# Regex Ignore Characters in quotes

Tags: regex

Is there a way to ignore text between certain characters? My current regular expression is including text between quotes. I need this to be ignored.

`raw_pmc_df\[\'(.*?)]`

Current Output:

`to_max(((100 * **raw_pmc_df['CPF_CPF_STAT_STALL']**) / **raw_pmc_df['CPF_CPF_STAT_BUSY']**).where((**raw_pmc_df['CPF_CPF_STAT_BUSY']** != 0), None))`

Desired Output:

`to_max(((100 * **raw_pmc_df['** CPF_CPF_STAT_STALL **']**) / **raw_pmc_df['** CPF_CPF_STAT_BUSY **']**).where((**raw_pmc_df['** CPF_CPF_STAT_BUSY **']** != 0), None))`

Comment: You can get a single match with separate parts. You can get the parts using 2 capture groups `(raw_pmc_df\[').*?('])` https://regex101.com/r/226v9l/1

Comment: What's the *input*?

Comment: It seems you want to remove these `raw` and `['` with `']`, and keep the contents that are in between, correct? Then use `raw_pmc_df\[\'(.*?)']` and replace with `$1` (or `\1`, depending on your programming environment). See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTZ0Fz/1).

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to use positive lookahead:

```
raw_pmc_df(?=\['[^']+'\])
```

The match will be

```
raw_pmc_df
```

You can add the square brackets afterwards.

There is no way to have split matches in common regex engines. In fact there is no need to: you design a regex with multiple capture groups:

```
(raw_pmc_df)(\[)(?:'[^']'+)(\])
```

The desired result is the concatenation of capture groups 1, 2, 3 (the quotes part does not count because of the `(:` parentheses). This way you do not need a positive lookahead.

In this particular example the regex is contrived as capture groups 2 and 3 contain strings known in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to remove these `raw` and `['` with `']`, and keep the contents that are in between.

If this is the case, you can use

```php
raw_pmc_df\[\'(.*?)']
```

and replace with `$1` (or `\1`, depending on your programming environment).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KTZ0Fz/1).

*Details*:

- `raw_pmc_df\[\'` - a `raw_pmc_df['` string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `']` - a `']` string.